# Duration how long a door is open, but same status records can be present more than once

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to calculate the difference between a status change, however the same state can have multiple records, see example below.

```
create table #DeviceMessages
(
    DoorName nvarchar(50),
    [StatusDoor] nvarchar(50),
    EventEndDate DatetIme
)

INSERT INTO #DeviceMessages
  (DoorName, [StatusDoor], EventEndDate)
VALUES
('Door 001', 'OPEN', '2017-03-23 16:50:42.143'),
('Door 001', 'CLOSED','2017-03-23 16:54:15.813'),
('Door 001', 'CLOSED','2017-03-23 17:53:12.757'),
('Door 001', 'OPEN', '2017-03-23 18:22:37.560'),
('Door 001', 'CLOSED','2017-03-23 18:28:01.197'),
('Door 001', 'CLOSED','2017-03-23 18:28:01.250'),
('Door 001', 'OPEN', '2017-03-23 18:29:40.593'),
('Door 001', 'OPEN', '2017-03-23 18:29:40.600'),
('Door 001', 'CLOSED','2017-03-23 18:34:53.827'),
('Door 001', 'CLOSED','2017-03-23 18:34:53.843'),
('Door 001', 'OPEN', '2017-03-23 18:42:56.463'),
('Door 001', 'OPEN', '2017-03-23 18:42:56.470'),
('Door 001', 'CLOSED','2017-03-23 18:46:32.550');
GO
```

It goes well when there are multiple CLOSED records, but it doesn't work when there are multiple OPEN records. At that moment I want the earliest OPEN record, compared to the nearest CLOSED record. I use the following statement:

```
    WITH DoorActivityWPairedTimes
AS
(SELECT [StatusDoor]
, EventEndDate 
, DeviceDoorOpen = DoorName
, DeviceDoorClosed = LEAD(DoorName, 1) OVER(ORDER BY DoorName, EventEndDate)
, DoorOpen = EventEndDate
, DoorClosed = LEAD(EventEndDate, 1) OVER(ORDER BY DoorName, EventEndDate)
, DoorOpenActivityDate = CAST(EventEndDate AS DATE)
, DoorDichtActivityDate = CAST(LEAD(EventEndDate, 1) OVER(ORDER BY DoorName, EventEndDate) AS DATE)
FROM #DeviceMessages)

SELECT DeviceDoorOpen Device
, EventEndDate
, DoorOpen
, DoorClosed 
, DATEDIFF(second, DoorOpen, DoorClosed) DurationOpenSec
FROM DoorActivityWPairedTimes
WHERE [StatusDoor] = 'OPEN'
  AND DoorOpen Is Not Null
  AND DeviceDoorOpen = DeviceDoorClosed
  AND DoorDichtActivityDate = DoorOpenActivityDate
  order by EventEndDate asc
```

The result of the query above:

```
+----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+
|  Device  |        DoorOpen         |        DoorClosed       | Dur.OpenSec |
+----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+
| Door 001 | 2017-03-23 16:50:42.143 | 2017-03-23 16:54:15.813 |         213 |
| Door 001 | 2017-03-23 18:22:37.560 | 2017-03-23 18:28:01.197 |         324 |
| Door 001 | 2017-03-23 18:29:40.593 | 2017-03-23 18:29:40.600 |           0 |
| Door 001 | 2017-03-23 18:29:40.600 | 2017-03-23 18:34:53.827 |         313 |
| Door 001 | 2017-03-23 18:42:56.463 | 2017-03-23 18:42:56.470 |           0 |
| Door 001 | 2017-03-23 18:42:56.470 | 2017-03-23 18:46:32.550 |         216 |
+----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+
```

**WANTED RESULT**

```
+----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+
|  Device  |        DoorOpen         |        DoorClosed       | Dur.OpenSec |
+----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+
| Door 001 | 2017-03-23 16:50:42.143 | 2017-03-23 16:54:15.813 |         213 |
| Door 001 | 2017-03-23 18:22:37.560 | 2017-03-23 18:28:01.197 |         324 |
| Door 001 | 2017-03-23 18:29:40.593 | 2017-03-23 18:34:53.827 |         313 |
| Door 001 | 2017-03-23 18:42:56.463 | 2017-03-23 18:46:32.550 |         216 |
+----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+
```

Can some helpme to make a query that makes the wanted result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO this question can be solved using a classic GROUPING AND WINDOWS solution.

**Reset point**

According to your question:

> I want the earliest OPEN record, compared to the nearest CLOSED record.

Two or more contiguous CLOSED records, require two different groups.

I've a set a reset point when:

- Last StatusDoor IS NULL (First record)
- Last StatusDoor is CLOSED and current StatusDoor is CLOSED. (Nearest CLOSED record).
- Current StatusDoor is OPEN and last StatusDoor is CLOSED (New Open/Closed event).

In addition, I've added a `MinMaxOrder` just to ensure OPEN events can be fetched before CLOSED events.

> ```
> WITH ResetPoint AS
> (
>     SELECT DoorName, [StatusDoor], EventEndDate,
>            CASE WHEN ([StatusDoor] = 'CLOSED'
>                      AND  COALESCE(LAG(StatusDoor) OVER (PARTITION BY DoorName ORDER BY EventEndDate), 'CLOSED') = 'CLOSED')
>                      OR
>                      ([StatusDoor] = 'OPEN'
>                      AND  COALESCE(LAG(StatusDoor) OVER (PARTITION BY DoorName ORDER BY EventEndDate), 'CLOSED') = 'CLOSED') 
>                 THEN 1 END IsReset
>     FROM   #DeviceMessages
> )
>    , SetGroup AS
>    (
>         SELECT DoorName, [StatusDoor], EventEndDate,
>                CASE WHEN StatusDoor = 'OPEN' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END MinMaxOrder,
>                COUNT(IsReset) OVER (PARTITION BY DoorName ORDER BY [EventEndDate]) grp
>         FROM   ResetPoint
>     )
> SELECT * FROM SetGroup;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> DoorName | StatusDoor | EventEndDate        | MinMaxOrder | grp
> :------- | :--------- | :------------------ | ----------: | --:
> Door 001 | OPEN       | 23/03/2017 16:50:42 |           0 |   1
> Door 001 | CLOSED     | 23/03/2017 16:54:15 |           1 |   1
> Door 001 | CLOSED     | 23/03/2017 17:53:12 |           1 |   2
> Door 001 | OPEN       | 23/03/2017 18:22:37 |           0 |   3
> Door 001 | CLOSED     | 23/03/2017 18:28:01 |           1 |   3
> Door 001 | CLOSED     | 23/03/2017 18:28:01 |           1 |   4
> Door 001 | OPEN       | 23/03/2017 18:29:40 |           0 |   5
> Door 001 | OPEN       | 23/03/2017 18:29:40 |           0 |   5
> Door 001 | CLOSED     | 23/03/2017 18:34:53 |           1 |   5
> Door 001 | CLOSED     | 23/03/2017 18:34:53 |           1 |   6
> Door 001 | OPEN       | 23/03/2017 18:42:56 |           0 |   7
> Door 001 | OPEN       | 23/03/2017 18:42:56 |           0 |   7
> Door 001 | CLOSED     | 23/03/2017 18:46:32 |           1 |   7
> ```

As far as each CLOSED event produces a new group, I can get MIN and MAX event of each group, and return only those groups with more than one record.

> ```
> --= Set a reset point each time the door opens and last event is a closed event
> --
> WITH ResetPoint AS
> (
>     SELECT DoorName, [StatusDoor], EventEndDate,
>            CASE WHEN ([StatusDoor] = 'CLOSED'
>                      AND  COALESCE(LAG(StatusDoor) OVER (PARTITION BY DoorName ORDER BY EventEndDate), 'CLOSED') = 'CLOSED')
>                      OR
>                      ([StatusDoor] = 'OPEN'
>                      AND  COALESCE(LAG(StatusDoor) OVER (PARTITION BY DoorName ORDER BY EventEndDate), 'CLOSED') = 'CLOSED') 
>                 THEN 1 END IsReset
>     FROM   #DeviceMessages
> )
>    --= Set a group for each reset point, and establish specific order as 0='OPEN', 1='CLOSED'
>    --
>    , SetGroup AS
>    (
>         SELECT DoorName, [StatusDoor], EventEndDate,
>                CASE WHEN StatusDoor = 'OPEN' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END MinMaxOrder,
>                COUNT(IsReset) OVER (PARTITION BY DoorName ORDER BY [EventEndDate]) grp
>         FROM   ResetPoint
>     )
>     --= Get max and min event date avoiding single CLOSED events.
>     --
>     SELECT   DoorName,
>              MIN(EventEndDate) DoorOpen,      
>              MAX(EventEndDate) DoorClosed,
>              DATEDIFF(SECOND, MIN(EventEndDate), MAX(EventEndDate)) DurationOpenSec
>     FROM     SetGroup
>     GROUP BY DoorName, grp
>     HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> DoorName | DoorOpen            | DoorClosed          | DurationOpenSec
> :------- | :------------------ | :------------------ | --------------:
> Door 001 | 23/03/2017 16:50:42 | 23/03/2017 16:54:15 |             213
> Door 001 | 23/03/2017 18:22:37 | 23/03/2017 18:28:01 |             324
> Door 001 | 23/03/2017 18:29:40 | 23/03/2017 18:34:53 |             313
> Door 001 | 23/03/2017 18:42:56 | 23/03/2017 18:46:32 |             216
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=0f845301ce21aceebebb7efb7f729947)*

Comment: Many thanx!. I understand the major part I have to dive into 'COALESCE'.

Comment: COALESCE returns the first NOT NULL member